# Passing variables from Jinja to database

Tags: python, sqlite, jinja2, web.py

I'm trying to figure out a way to pass a dynamic URL with webpy that will render a Jinja template with information about the information that was passed. Specifically I have a item database that should be able to take whatever item ID is in the URL and render a template with further information about that item.

To simply the problem, I've hardcoded the value 1043374545 for demonstrations purposes, but I'm hoping that this line will be come dynamic once this initial problem is solved.

```
urls = ('/1043374545', 'view_item')

class view_item:
    def GET(self, itemID):
        item_info = sqlitedb.detailInfo(request)
        return render_template('view_item.html', item = item_info)
```

As of now I isolated the issue to having to do with something related to passing the value 1043374545 into the view_item function. Any thoughts on how I can pass a dynamic number within a URL into view_item?

Comment: This is pretty much the fundamental thing that a web framework does. However you haven't told us what web framework you are using. I suggest you go and read the documentation for that framework and see how it manages URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply put:

```
urls = (('/([0-9]*)', 'view_item'),)
```

[0-9]* will tell webpy to only accept numbers after the "/".
Then you can use that value in your GET function, it will be under itemID as you specified in your GET parameter.

```
class view_item:
    def GET(self, itemID):
        item_info = sqlitedb.detailInfo(itemID)
        return render_template('view_item.html', item = item_info)
```

check this link for more details:
http://webpy.org/cookbook/url_handling